# In SQLite Order By Datetime desc returning wrong data

Tags: sqlite

I have one doubt in Sqlite.dteTime DataType is Varchar(200) in Table structure. I want to get result in order by Date Time.

**"select dteTime from table ORDER BY  dteTime Desc",**

**getting result is**

"05/05/2015 12:38:43 PM"

"05/05/2015 12:38:43 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:57:04 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:57:04 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:51:25 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:51:25 AM"

"05/05/2015 04:38:35 PM"

"05/05/2015 04:00:48 PM"

"05/04/2015 11:38:43 PM"

**Instead of this how can i get(Expected Result)**

"05/05/2015 04:38:35 PM"

"05/05/2015 04:00:48 PM"

"05/05/2015 12:38:43 PM"

"05/05/2015 10:57:04 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:57:04 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:51:25 AM"

"05/05/2015 10:51:25 AM"

"05/05/2015 12:38:43 AM"

"05/04/2015 11:38:43 PM"

**Any solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Use a date format such as unixtime (seconds/milliseconds since an epoch) or ISO 8601 (e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`) for your datetime stamps so that the natural sort order is also the chronological order.

Comment: SQLite may randomly sort the columns if you have the same datetime for multiple items. ..

Answer (score 2):

SQLite doesn't have an internal date type. It's sorting alphabetically in a case like this. You can write your dates in an iso format or [transform](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) them to do the sort.